# Accessing an array contained in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

This is my first post, so I apologize if I do something wrong or if that is a bad question. For my current project, I am trying to access an array that is pointed to by a struct.
Here's the struct:

```
struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity of the array */
};
```

I thought that the correct way to change and access the element would be:

```
    v->data[0]=5.0;
    v->data[1]=10.0;
    printf("The value is %d\n",v->data[0]);
    printf("The value is %d\n",v->data[1]);
```

What I'm instead getting is:

The value is 1123954688

The value is 1123954688

Would somebody mind showing me what I'm doing wrong? I've looked around on here but unfortunately couldn't find anything that helped.

edit: Thank you for the replies I've received so far. The memory is allocated elsewhere in the project. I chose not to include all code for the project since as it stands it's around 400 lines, and I didn't think it would be helpful to include all of it, and would be a lot to sort through. If necessary I will do so.

edit2: Here's the code slimmed down.
From main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dynamicArray.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    DynArr *dyn;
    dyn = createDynArr(2);
    printf("\n\nTesting addDynArr...\n");
    addDynArr(&dyn, 3);
    addDynArr(&dyn, 4);
}
```

From the implementation file:

```
struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};

DynArr* createDynArr(int cap)
{
    assert(cap > 0);
    DynArr *r = (DynArr *)malloc(sizeof( DynArr));
    assert(r != 0);
    initDynArr(r,cap);
    return r;
}
void initDynArr(DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    assert(capacity > 0);
    assert(v!= 0);
    v->data = (TYPE *) malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;
}
void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{
    /* FIXME: You will write this function */
    v->data[0]=5.0;
    v->data[1]=10.0;
    printf("The value is %d\n",v->data[0]);
    printf("The value is %d\n",v->data[1]); 
}
```

From the header file:

```
#include<math.h>

#ifndef DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INCLUDED
#define DYNAMIC_ARRAY_INCLUDED 1


# ifndef TYPE
# define TYPE     double 
# define TYPE_SIZE sizeof(double)
# endif

# ifndef EQ
# define EQ(A, B) (fabs(A - B) < 10e-7)
# endif

typedef struct DynArr DynArr;

DynArr *createDynArr(int cap);
void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val);
```

I believe that's all of it. I know that the values I'm passing to the function are not the values that are being assigned, I'm just trying to figure out how to access the array though the stuct and pointer

Comment: Mind defining what TYPE is? Your initialization makes it likely that it's not an integer type, then your format string in the printf would be off...

Comment: I'm guessing that as themel explained the type of your array is responsible for the output you're getting! It should be an array of int so int*

Comment: @tvr2006 did you assign memory to `data`?

Comment: I do not see an array, but dereferencing a pointer using array-_semantics_.

Comment: Questions like this should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That would ensure that all the relevant information is present. As it is, you have left out important details required to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. TYPE is a double. @Ediac, yes, memory has been assigned, I apologize for not stating that.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for your time and help. The issue ended up being my using %d instead of %f in the printf() statements.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not an array but a pointer (As per your comment `/* pointer to the data array */`) of type `TYPE` but there is no any array. (I suspect that `TYPE` is `typedef` of `float`). You need to allocate memory before storing the values -

```
       //Add this line rest of the code is same
       v->data = malloc(2*sizeof(TYPE)); //Assuming you need to store only two values
       v->data[0]=5.0;
       v->data[1]=10.0;
       printf("The value is %d\n",v->data[0]);
       printf("The value is %d\n",v->data[1]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't not allocating memory throw a segmentation fault instead of a wrong output ?

Comment: @LonniBesançon: C does not have the concept of _segmentation fault_. This is one possible incarnation of _undefined behaviour_. But why should `malloc` present UB at all?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have faced segmentation fault in c before when not allocating memory correctly. Just a quick google search gave me an example here of a segmentation fault in C: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-segmentation-fault-156985/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The memory is allocated elsewhere, I apologize for not stating that. I didn't include all code for the project because it's currently around 400 lines total. TYPE in this case is a double.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you should change v->data[0]'s type, maybe *((int *)v->data[0]) or any type you want.

ye, float and int are stored in very different format...